# How can I find the origin of my React build error?

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I just migrated my React app from Flow to Typescript using Khan/flow-to-ts. When building I get an error:

```
$ npm run build

> my-app-name@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal.
$
```

This is the only output. How do I get more details about the error, like a stack trace or at least the source file where the error occurs?

Comment: you can try using `react-scripts start`, this should create a dev server in which you should get the various compilation errors

Comment: ah you are right, so simple :) I was looking for a compiler argument, thx!